# stuck in park no power to dash or windows

Tags: electrical

My Honda out of the blue would not go from park and so I had to use shift lock release and I have no power to my windows or dash what would cause this?

Comment: Can you add more information please?  Does the car run?  Does it start?  If it doesn't, what happens?  Are there any sounds?  Where are they coming from?  What is the model and year?   :-)  If you can add that into your question that would be great.  Anything else you can share as well.  There is an edit button you can use to add the info to your question.   Thanks and Cheers!!!!

Comment: Yes it runs its a1996 Honda civic its never done this before went to back up and it would not come out of park no sounds that I heard I think I smelt like wires a little before it happened my lights work all of them no power to dash and windows?...

Comment: It does start that was replaced not to long ago.the car has given me problems but never this it is also drinking way more gas...

Answer (score 6):

I have seen a very similar fault on a car.  The ignition switch is often designed to disconnect power to all the ancillaries while the ignition switch is in the start position.  If the ignition switch becomes faulty, it may be providing power to the engine running circuitry, but not the rest.  It may also account for the burning smell.

Have a smell near the ignition switch, it may indicate that the fault is with the ignition switch.